# JavaFX - How to position the axis label to avoid conflicting with the tick marks

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

The below code is a simple line chart where the yAxis tick labels are wide in terms of their character length/width. The yAxis label positioned by default is placed too close to the yAxis, meaning the text conflicts with the tick marks. Is it possible to avoid this by increasing the gap between the label and the axis?

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 2);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1.3378, 1.3390, 0.0001);
        xAxis.setLabel("xAxis");
        yAxis.setLabel("yAxis");
        yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis){
            @Override public String toString(Number object){
                return String.format("%1.4f", object); }
        });

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        final XYChart.Data d1 = new XYChart.Data(0.0,1.3379);
        final XYChart.Data d2 = new XYChart.Data(2.0,1.3387);
        final XYChart.Data d3 = new XYChart.Data(2.5,1.3385);
        final XYChart.Data d4 = new XYChart.Data(3.5,1.3387);
        final XYChart.Data d5 = new XYChart.Data(8.0,1.3378);
        final XYChart.Data d6 = new XYChart.Data(9.5,1.3388);

        series.getData().addAll(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to locate the label of an axis.

For Example to move the Label 10 Pixel to the left, just use:

```
lineChart.getYAxis()
       .lookup(".axis-label")
       .setStyle("-fx-label-padding: -10 0 0 0;");
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to relocate "yAxis" label or increase the gap, but you may want to use the following workaround to avoid the text conficts:

```
lineChart.getYAxis().setTickLabelRotation(-90);
```

And you will get the following chart:
[image]